# Average sum of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

3 balls are drawn from an urn with 30 balls, labelled 1-30, with replacement.
What is the average of their sum?

Since we draw the balls with replacement, we can get any combinations of 3 out of 30 numbers, which are 4060. Smallest value is 3 and largest is 90 but then what?
Smallest value appears 3 times, largest also 3 times.

Comment: What is the expectation for each ball? How many balls are there?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Work out the average for each draw - they are independent events.

Alternatively pair the triples $(a, b, c)$ and $(31-a, 31-b, 31-c)$ - these cannot be the same, because the sum of all the elements is $93$, which is odd. This can be used for the "without replacement" version too.

Comment: We are looking for the average (or mean??) of the sum, not the average of the 3 numbers. So I guess there is no average for each draw, right?

Comment: @Alex.vollenga What is the mean of the sum of two independent variables?

Comment: Their sum divided by 2, right?

Comment: @Alex.vollenga If variables are independent you can take the average/mean before computing the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $A=(a,b,c)$ be an arbitrary triplet. We define $S(A)=a+b+c$ , and $P(A)$ to denote the sum of the triplet and the possibility of getting that triplet, respectively. Then, the average will converge to:$$\sum_r{P(A_r)}{S(A_r)}$$ Here, $r$ implies that summation is held over all possible triplets. Since each triplet has the same possibility of being drawn, $P(A_r)$ is $\frac{1}{{30}\choose{3}}$. To find $S(A_r)$ , we use the fact that each number appears ${29}\choose{2}$ times in all triplets. So, we have:
$$ \sum_r{P(A_r)}{S(A_r)} = \frac{1}{{30}\choose{3}}\sum_{i=1}^{30}{\binom{29}{2}i} = 46.5 $$ You can solve the same problem for balls being drawn one by one and see that the average is $15.5$ which is the third of what we found. To generalise, for $N$ balls numbered from $1$ to $N$ and $k$ draws each time, the average is: $$ \sum_r{P_r}{S_r} = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{k}}\sum_{i=1}^N{\binom{N-1}{k-1}i}=\frac{k}{N}\frac{N(N+1)}{2}=\frac{k(N+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The average of one ball is $\frac {31}2$.  The average of three balls is then $\frac {93}2$.  It actually does not matter whether you draw with replacement or not.  The linearity of expectation still applies.